# How to configure CodeLite IDE to use C++ and SFML library? (Windows/Linux) Configuration complete solution

Tags: c++, sfml, 2d-games, codelite

How to configure "CodeLite" IDE for being able to develop in C++ with the library SFML?

Here below is my complete solution...

ENJOY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complete solution is described within Windows but this also works in Linux

### **1) Downloads on SFML Website (Download section)** :

https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/

- The needed compiler
- The corresponding SFML libraries

[image]

Pay attention to :

1. The compiler name (here MinGW)
2. The compiler version (here 7.3.0)
3. The compiler target environment (here 32 bits)

**The compiler and the version of SFML have to match 100%!!!**

### **2) Copy the compiler directory and the SMFL directory on your hard disk**

[image]

### **3) Define the compiler in CodeLite**

From top menu "Settings/Build Settings..."

[image]

### **4) Create your project**

[image]

### **5) Define project's compiler**

1. Right click on the project
2. Choose "Settings..."
3. In section General -> choose the compiler

[image]

### **6) Compiler settings (within the project)**

In "Compiler" section ...

1. Define "Include Paths" = `C:\SFML-2.5.1\include`
2. "Preprocessors" = `SFML_STATIC`

[image]

**7) Linker settings (within the project)**

In "Linker" section ...

1. Define "Libraries Search Path" = `C:\SFML-2.5.1\lib`
2. "Libraries" = 
   `sfml-graphics
   sfml-window
   sfml-audio
   sfml-network
   sfml-system`

[image]

---

[image]

### **8) Add the following code to the project (for testing purpose)**

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;


}
```

### **9) Compile the project**

This will not compile cause you have to copy/paste some .dll files into the compilation folder

### **10) Add Dlls to the bin directory**

### [image]

1. The executable compiled
2. File "libstdc++-6.dll" from "C:\mingw32\bin"
3. All Dlls from "C:\SFML-2.5.1\bin"

INFO : some additionnal .dll files would be needed (eventually some from /bin of the compiler directory)

### **11) Recompile**

### **12) Execute**

If it works...

[image]

### **13) Enjoy!!!**